# Помогите понять, почему не открывает меню

Tags: html, css, форум

Сразу скажу, что я в принципе даже не знаю куда смотреть (форум на mybb). Дальше все по-порядку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видите эту стрелку напротив приветствия? Структура кода такая:

Стрелка - класс fa fa-caret-down из font awesome, она обернута в ID "ddmenu", то есть:

```
<a href="" id="ddnmenu">С возвращением, admin! <i class="fa fa-caret-down">::before</i></a>
```

Я так понял, при нажатии на любой место (div же), должно всплывать меню, которого нет.

В консоли выводится следующее:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: use_xmlhttprequest is not defined
at (index):91
```

в котором и присутствует div #ddnmenu, только почему-то задокументированный (я ничего не документировал):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // <!--
            if(use_xmlhttprequest == "1"){
                $("#ddnmenu").popupMenu();
            }
        // -->
    </script>
```

Весь прикол в том, что (я уже сказал, что я ничего не документировал, форум держу на localhost пока что, так что никто залезть не мог) я даже не знаю, где находится этот кусок кода. Я искал в поиске (через программу) по слову "ddnmenu" по всем папкам (включая вложенные), нашел только XML файл со всем содержимым. Но также (очень много приколусов возникает) замечу, что по дефолту он задокументирован (кусок тот самый верхний). То есть кроме этого файла больше ничего нет. Вопрос: Что я должен сделать, если я найти-то ничего не могу?

UPD: Гуглил проблему, нашел еще 4 человека, везде был дан ответ, чтобы я проверил Js файлы в папке и проверил, включена ли функция Enable XMLHttp request. Всем все помогло, мне нет. Все на месте было по дефолту, все работало по дефолту. Получается что что-то не так с localhost? Хотя и это отрицаю (но, возможно, что-то присутствует), потому что буквально еще вчера все работало на локалке. Полностью удалял тему, папку, ставил чисто, ничего не помогает. Что за идиотизм - я не знаю. Если обновлять тему, то не в админ панели (там такой функции нет), но она свежая. Проблема с

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: use_xmlhttprequest is not defined
at (index):91
```

после переустановки пропала, но меню до сих пор не хочет вылезать. Глухой тупик, или где лазейка есть - я не знаю. Не знаю как и вы попытаетесь помочь мне. Это просто ириски (тут подразумевался мат). То ли святой водой поливать, то ли попа вызывать, крайний вариант.